# Dropdown list not displaying with textfield in form

Tags: jsp

I've written a JSP that has a form and the form contains a dropdown list and a texfield. The dropdown is populated from a mysql database using beans which act as DAOs and DTOs. Problem is the dropdown doesn't display the values from the database but when I remove the textfield from the form and leave only the dropdown, it displays fine. someone knows why? Please let me know what to do. The code for the forms is below:

JSP that works:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:useBean id="camp" scope="session" class="p1.campusDao"/>
<%--
    Document   : addCamp
    Created on : May 20, 2011, 11:28:31 AM
    Author     : ken
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color:#AFC7C7;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            div.wrapper {
                margin-left: 10%;
                margin-right: 10%;
                background-color:#6D7B8D;
                height: 607px;
                padding-top:0px;
                border: thin solid #000000;
            }

            div#image{
                padding-top:1%;
                padding-bottom:1%;
            }
            div#adminlogin{
                width:35%;
                height:40%;
                background-color:#AFC7C7;
                border-width:thin;
                border-style:solid;
                border-color:#000000;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align:left;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            hr {
                height:1px;
                color:#000000;
                background-color:#000000;
                width:99%;
                margin-left: 0 ;
                margin-right: auto ;
                border-style:solid;
            }

            .inputtext {
                width: 250px;
                height: 30px;
                Font-Family:Arial;
                Font-Size:18px
            }

        </style>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function clearText(field){

                if (field.defaultValue == field.value) field.value = '';
                else if (field.value == '') field.value = field.defaultValue;

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="image">
                <p>
                    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/logo.gif"
                         alt="banner"
                         width=100%
                         height="100"
                         /></p>
            </div><!--end of image div-->
            <div id=adminlogin >
                <p style="text-align:center">Adding Hostel</p>
                <hr/>
                <form id="cam" method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getHos">
                    <select name="campuses" size="1" id="camps">
                        <c:forEach items="${camp.stateList}" var="ca">
                            <%--<option value="1"><c:out value="${ca.campnm}"/></option>--%>
                            <option>${ca.campnm}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <input type="Submit" name="cmdSub" value="SUBMIT">
                </form>
                <p STYLE="color : #E41B17;">${message}</p>
                <c:remove var="message" scope="session" />



            </div><%--end of admin login div--%>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSP with textfield in form and doesn't display dropdown elements in UI:

```
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<jsp:useBean id="campu" scope="session" class="p1.campusDao"/>
<%--
    Document   : addCamp
    Created on : May 20, 2011, 11:28:31 AM
    Author     : ken
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color:#AFC7C7;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            div.wrapper {
                margin-left: 10%;
                margin-right: 10%;
                background-color:#6D7B8D;
                height: 607px;
                padding-top:0px;
                border: thin solid #000000;
            }

            div#image{
                padding-top:1%;
                padding-bottom:1%;
            }
            div#adminlogin{
                width:35%;
                height:40%;
                background-color:#AFC7C7;
                border-width:thin;
                border-style:solid;
                border-color:#000000;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align:left;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            hr {
                height:1px;
                color:#000000;
                background-color:#000000;
                width:99%;
                margin-left: 0 ;
                margin-right: auto ;
                border-style:solid;
            }

            .inputtext {
                width: 250px;
                height: 30px;
                Font-Family:Arial;
                Font-Size:18px
            }

        </style>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function clearText(field){

                if (field.defaultValue == field.value) field.value = '';
                else if (field.value == '') field.value = field.defaultValue;

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="image">
                <p>
                    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/logo.gif"
                         alt="banner"
                         width=100%
                         height="100"
                         /></p>
            </div><!--end of image div-->
            <div id=adminlogin >
                <p style="text-align:center">Adding Hostel</p>
                <hr/>
                <form method=POST id="hostel" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getHos">
                    <p/>
                    <%--The textfield for hostel name--%>
                    <label>Hostel Name<input type="text" id="hostel"  name="hosNm" value=""/></label><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <label>Campus Name <select name="campuses" size="1" id="hostel">
                        <c:forEach items="${campu.stateList}" var="cam">
                            <%--<option value="1"><c:out value="${cam.campnm}"/></option>--%>
                            <option>${cam.campnm}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </select></label>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" style="font-size:14pt; margin-left: 158px; height: 30px;"/>

                </form>
                <p STYLE="color : #E41B17;">${message}</p>
                <c:remove var="message" scope="session" />



            </div><%--end of admin login div--%>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any difference expect of the indentation. Please verify the code snippets.

Comment: oh no. I just pasted twice. But the second form has this:`<label>Hostel Name<input type="text" id="hostel" class="inputtext" name="hosNm" value=""
                                             onFocus="clearText(this)" onBlur="clearText(this)"/></label><br/>` which when I remove it from the form, the dropdown is able to display

Comment: Please edit it in your question. I don't see odd things. What exactly do you mean with "display"? In the UI as you see it in the browser viewport or in the generated HTML source as you see by rightclicking page and choosing *View Source*? If in the UI, probably your CSS is being overzealous. You might want to disable it just for testing or to post the relevant CSS code along.

Comment: I'm failing to edit the question. But what I mean by display is that when there is the textfield in the form, the dropdown list in the UI is shown but with no elements. But when I remove the textfield from the form, the dropdown list is shown with the elements in it. I've actually removed the CSS and javascript and left the textfield with only this line`<label>Hostel Name<input type="text" id="hostel"  name="hosNm" value=""/></label>` but still not getting elements in the dropdown

Comment: I don't see any odd things. You must have some HTML/XML syntax error which caused `<c:forEach>` to fail. To be sure, do you see the `<option>` elements in the generated HTML output? Rightclick page, *View Source* and on. Also try to inline `${campu.stateList}` plain before or after the text field to see if it prints the full list.

Comment: There is actually no option in `<c:forEach>` tags. There is only `<option></option>` in the source

Comment: Thus, the `${campu.stateList}` is empty? Are you requesting the page through a servlet which fills that list and then displays the JSP? Thus you don't request the JSP directly without invoking the servlet?

Comment: Wait, you have a `<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>` instead of `/core` in your second JSP? Do you really have two separate files?

Comment: With inline I just mean ... put `${campu.stateList}` straight in JSP. E.g. `<p>State list: ${campu.stateList}</p>`.

Comment: Actually, I'm requesting the JSP directly. It uses a bean that acts as a DAO with another class that acts as a DTO to generate the list and place in the JSP. But I'm a little surprised, why should it give the options in the dropdown list in the absence of the textfield only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second JSP (do you really have two separate JSP files?) you have a

```
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
```

instead of

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Fix it accordingly. Then the `<c:xxx>` tags will be parsed.

I'd also get rid of `<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>` since it is useless and only allows for poor practices (*scriptlets*).

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. I actually copied the first file and edited the copy and seems that is where I missed out the tag issue. It's working now. You are good!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have done a rightclick and *View Source* on the second JSP then you should have faced an unparsed `<c:forEach>` tag. This should already have turned on some light in the head ... It doesn't belong there in the generated HTML output! ;)